# Search NSArray and return the id of the row

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I would like to search an array and return the row number i.e. 0-10. The reason is I am loading information from a database and need to auto select a value in a uipicker view and from my understanding you can only select things in a uipicker view by the row id. So I would like to search the array with a string and return the row id so that I can tell the uipicker view what row to select.

Comment: An `NSArray` of `NSString`? What's wrong with a regular `for` loop?

Comment: Be more specific about how you want to search.  Do you want to match the search string exactly? Look for something that contains the search string?

Comment: Sorry, I want to match the search string exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
NSInteger index = [array indexOfObject:@"string"];
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I dont understand why someone down voted my question.

Comment: @Jonathan no problem, I'm happy to help. I think the downvote is for the fact that this answer can easily be found for the first time browsing the docs (but the downvote is not mine).

Comment: Oh I must have missed that because I had been searching for a while. Oh well.